# How to Inspect the Queue Processing a Celery Task

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, datadog

I'm currently leveraging celery for periodic tasks. I am new to celery. I have two workers running two different queues. One for slow background jobs and one for jobs user's queue up in the application.

I am monitoring my tasks on datadog because it's an easy way to confirm my workers a running appropriately.

What I want to do is after each task completes, record which queue the task was completed on.

```
@after_task_publish.connect()
def on_task_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    statsd.increment("celery.on_task_publish.start.increment")

    task = celery.tasks.get(sender)
    queue_name = task.queue

    statsd.increment("celery.on_task_publish.increment", tags=[f"{queue_name}:{task}"])
```

The following function is something that I implemented after researching the celery docs and some StackOverflow posts, but it's not working as intended. I get the first statsd increment but the remaining code does not execute.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to inspect inside/after each task completes, what queue processed the task.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question says *is there a way to inspect inside/after each task completes* - I'm assuming you haven't tried this celery-result-backend stuff. So you could check out this feature which is provided by Celery itself : *`Celery-Result-Backend / Task-result-Backend`* .
It is very useful for storing results of your celery tasks.
Read through this => https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings

---

Once you get an idea of how to setup this result-backend, Search for `result_extended` key (in the same link) to be able to add `queue-names` in your task return values.

Number of options are available - Like you can setup these results to go to any of these :

```
Sql-DB / NoSql-DB / S3 / Azure / Elasticsearch / etc
```

---

I have made use of this *`Result-Backend`* feature with *`Elasticsearch`* and this how my task results are stored :

[image]

It is just a matter of adding few configurations in `settings.py` file as per your requirements. Worked really well for my application. And I have a weekly cron that clears only `successful results` of tasks - since we don't need the results anymore - and I can see only `failed results` *(like the one in image).*

These were main keys for my requirement : `task_track_started` and `task_acks_late` along with `result_backend`

Comment: Ok I'm closer here. I have a redis backend and added result_extended. I see the queue inside of the result values. How do I find the function name that called the task with the task_id? That I am a little confused on. Tying the function back to the exact task on my backend.

Comment: i dint get you . please add some screenshots or data so i can understand . one doubt, is `redis` good for a `result-backend` ?