# celery consume send_task response

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, amqp, django-celery

In django application I need to call an external rabbitmq, running on a windows server and using some application there, where the django app runs on a linux server.

I'm currently able to add a task to the queue by using the celery `send_task`:

```
app.send_task('tasks', kwargs=self.get_input(), queue=Queue('queue_async', durable=False))
```

My settings looks like:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = CELERY_CONFIG['broker_url']
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"max_retries": 3, "interval_start": 0, "interval_step": 0.2, "interval_max": 0.5}

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

What I'm not sure about is how I can get and parse the response, since the send_task only returns a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks that helped for the understanding. So since I want to further process the answer I use rpc as already defined in the config I had in the example.

What I found usefull was this example, because most python celery examples assume that the consumer is the same application, that describes the interaction to a Java app [Celery-Java](https://github.com/crabhi/celery-java) since it gives a good example on how to request from python side.

Therefore my implementation is now:

```
result = app.signature('tasks', kwargs=self.get_input(), queue=Queue('queue_async', durable=False)).delay().get()
```

which waits and parses the result.

Comment: using `rpc` as backend will store the task results in `queues` . is that your desired functionality ?

Comment: I think so. My goal is basically to send from python (running on an ubuntu server) the tasks to another application (Java running on windows). The python task should wait for the response (synchronously) and then process the result further and return to the client. Therefore I think `rpc` is the intended `result_backend` setting, or am I wrong?

Comment: okay. i'm really not sure of that. you can try it out . do update me here if that solved your issue .

Comment: yes I tested it and it actually works as intended. So I assume using `rpc`is the right thing to do as described above. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store results of your task , you could use this parameter `result_backend` or `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` depending on the version of celery you're using.

Complete list of Configuration options can be found here (search for `result_backend` on this page) => https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html

Many options are available to store results - `SQL DBs , NoSQL DBs, Elasticsearch, Memcache, Redis, etc,etc` . Choose as per your project stack.

Comment: you can check my detailed answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069822/6490744