# Problems with celery + celery workers

Tags: python, celery

So I'm completely new to celery and I have been trying to follow along with the tutorial that is in the documentation and I've run into problems. The issue arises when I cannot access the results of celery workers. This is my code in a file named `tasks.py` (I have rabbitMQ setup):

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://localhost')


@app.task
def adding(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I run a worker with this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

After running that command this is the output code:

```
 -------------- celery@Tims-PC v4.4.6 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 2020-08-01 00:38:28
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x43bbcd0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.adding

[2020-08-01 00:38:28,270: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,406: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,804: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 14948 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,811: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 4396 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,813: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 488 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,814: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 15252 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,814: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 9816 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,817: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 21044 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,822: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 1052 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,826: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 20656 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,832: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 21240 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,839: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 3036 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,847: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 13052 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:28,847: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 17780 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:29,333: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 10320 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:29,333: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 22176 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:29,335: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 13656 calling self.run()
[2020-08-01 00:38:29,664: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-08-01 00:38:29,671: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\users\timothee legros\pycharmprojects\celerytesting\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\pidbox.py:74: UserWarning: A node named celery@Tims-P
C is already using this process mailbox!

Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
you give each node a unique node name!

  warnings.warn(W_PIDBOX_IN_USE.format(node=self))
[2020-08-01 00:38:29,677: INFO/MainProcess] celery@Tims-PC ready.
```

Once here I cannot type anything and ctrl-c only prints that I should press ctrl-c again to quit but when I do nothing happens. This is not my main issue. My main issue is when I use the python console to use the worker as follows:

```
from tasks import adding
result = adding.delay(3, 4)
```

That code returns a AsyncResult but 2 things happen:

1. No info is updated in the original terminal window to indicate that any worker processed a task and
2. when I try to access the result like this:

```
result.get()
```

The python console freezes and I can no longer type or anything. In order to regain control of the python console I have to ctrl-c which raises a socket.timeout error.

Does anyone have an idea to fix my issue? Tutorials everywhere show that the original terminal window where the worker was first started should update when a task is run and result.get() should return the data returned by a task.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can see this line on your worker console -

```
task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
```

I guess you should try to run your `celery-worker` using the `-E` option like so :

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -E
```

I'm not so sure of this, but you can give it a try.

---

Also you could refer my answer here - for storing results of your tasks : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387375/6490744